# Unsafe power off on power button pressed

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown, ubuntu-server, dell-poweredge

I have Ubuntu Server 13.10 set up on a Dell PowerEdge 2950 (Gen II), and whenever I press (not press and hold) the power button the machine doesn't safely shutdown (it instantly powers off), though it does flash the message "acpid: exiting" before turning off.

If I instead run shutdown -h now, it goes through the usual cycle of stopping processes, unmounting filesystems, etc...

Any ideas why this might be? I want the power button to safely shut down the system (unless I hold it down, of course).

Comment: Have you checked BIOS settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking in the manual, the power button only performs a graceful shutdown if the operating system is ACPI compliant.

By the looks of the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/72900/53851), you might need to get the `acpi-support` package or, according to the second answer, the `acpid` package.

You could give either of those a try.

Hardware Information directly from the Dell Poweredge 2950 Manual:

Page 13:

> **NOTE:** If you turn off the system using the power button 
>   and the system is running an ACPI-compliant operating 
>   system, the system performs a graceful shutdown before 
>   the power is turned off. If the system is not running an 
>   ACPI-compliant operating system, the power is turned off 
>   immediately after the power button is pressed

Page 44:

> **Power Button** (Enabled default)
>
> Turns system's power off and on.
>
> • If you turn off the system using the power button and the system is running an 
>   ACPI-compliant operating system, the system can perform an orderly shutdown 
>   before power is turned off.
>
> • If the system is not running an ACPI-compliant operating system, power is turned 
>   off immediately after the power button is pressed.
>
> The button is enabled in the System Setup program. When disabled, the button 
>   can only turn on system power.
>
> **NOTE:** You can still turn on the system by using the power button, even if the Power 
>   Button option is set to Disabled.

Source: ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-2950_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf

Comment: I have the acpid package. I'll try the acpid-support package as well.

Comment: Well, it seems to have solved itself somehow. Possibly through an automatically-installed security update. Strange, but I'll accept this answer since it does give all the information I would have needed.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a conflict between acpid and systemd both attempting a shutdown and the result being an immediate poweroff. 
Work-around: Disable either.

Disabling acpid: comment out the lines in `/etc/acpi/events/powerbtn` (or delete that file)
Disabling systemd: edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and add `HandlePowerKey=ignore` to the `[Login]` section.